# assignment in python

Tags: python

I know that "variable assignment" in python is in fact a binding / re-bindign of a name (the variable) to an object.

This brings the question: is it possible to have proper assignment in python, eg make an object equal to another object?

I guess there is no need for that in python:

1. Inmutable objects cannot be 'assigned to' since they can't be changed
2. Mutable objects could potentially be assigned to, since they can change, and this could be useful, since you may want to manipulate a copy of dictionary separately from the original one. However, in these cases the python philosophy is to offer a cloning method on the mutable object, so you can bind a copy rather than the original.

So I guess the answer is that there is no assignment in python, the best way to mimic it would be binding to a cloned object

I simply wanted to share the question in case I'm missing something important here

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Both Lie Ryan and Sven Marnach answers are good, I guess the overall answer is a mix of both:

For user defined types, use the idiom:

> a.**dict** = dict(b.**dict**)

(I guess this has problems as well if the assigned class has redefined attribute access methods, but lets not be fussy :))

For mutable built-ins (lists and dicts) use the cloning / copying methods they provide (eg slices, update)

finally inmutable built-ins can't be changed so can't be assigned

I'll choose Lie Ryan because it's an elegant idiom that I hadn't thought of.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about a deep copy?  Is that what you mean by "binding to a cloned object"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This brings the question: is it
>   possible to have proper assignment in
>   python, eg make an object equal to
>   another object?

Yes you can:

```
a.__dict__ = dict(b.__dict__)
```

will do the default assignment semantic in C/C++ (i.e. do a shallow assignment).

The problem with such generalized assignment is that it never works for everybody. In C++, you can override the assignment operator since you always have to pick whether you want a fully shallow assignment, fully deep assignment, or any shade between fully deep copy and fully shallow copy.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are right with your characterization of assignment in Python -- I just would like to add a different method of cloning and ways of assignment in special cases.

"Copy-constructing" a *mutable* built-in Python object will yield a (shallow) copy of that object:

```
l = [2, 3]
m = list(l)
l is m
--> False
```

[**Edit**: As pointed out by Paul McGuire in the comments, the behaviour of a "copy contructor" (forgive me the C++ terminology) for a *immutable* built-in Python object is implementation dependent -- you might get a copy or just the same object.  But because the object is immutable anyway, you shouldn't care.]

The copy constructor could be called generically by `y = type(x)(x)`, but this seems a bit cryptic.  And of course, there is the [`copy`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#module-copy) module which allows for shallow and deep copies.

Some Python objects allow assignment.  For example, you can assign to a list without creating a new object:

```
l = [2, 3]
m = l
l[:] = [3, 4, 5]
m
--> [3, 4, 5]
```

For dictionaries, you could use the `clear()` method followed by `update(otherdict)` to assign to a dictionary without creating a new object.  For a set `s`, you can use

```
s.clear()
s |= otherset
```

Comment: Your "copy constructor" assumptions *may* hold true for the built-in Python classes, but they are not generally guaranteed for all classes and objects.  I can very easily create an immutable class that takes an instance of itself for construction, but makes an entirely different object with the same values, such that `copy == original` is True, but `copy is original` is False.

Comment: I just noticed that you already qualified your answer to restrict it to the built-in classes.

Comment: A brief experiment with Jython 2.5.0 shows that this does not hold true for strings. : >>> a = "SLJDFSDLJ" >>> b = str(a) >>> b is a False   - what you have described is an implementation optimization specific to CPython, but not guaranteed by the Python language spec.

Comment: For your own classes, you can always add some kind of `assign()` method if you need it -- that's why I focussed on the built-in types.

Comment: @Paul McGuire: I'm surprised!  I just tested with Python 2.6.6 and I get `True`...  To be honest, I'm really not sure any more the behaviour I described is guaranteed.  I will investigate...

Comment: @Paul McGuire: OK, you are right.  I will edit my post and just omit the statements on immutable types - they are not relevant to the question anyway :)

Comment: A separate `assign()` method is unnecessary - if you want to implement an immutable class, you might as well implement the same optimization in `__new__` - just check if the initial arg `isinstance(type(self))` and if so, just return it instead of a new object.  My point was that this kind of optimization is purely up to the implementer, much like the *convention* that passing the repr of an instance to the class will make a copy of the instance, and should not be counted on as a rule, as your answer would imply.

Comment: Yes, the original point of the OP was the distinction between name binding and address assignment. I think Asimov said that more insights are gained not when we say "Eureka!", but when we say "Hmmm, that's odd...".

Comment: @Paul McGuire: The bit with the `assign()` method was about mutable classes only.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are missing anything.

I like to picture variables in python as the name written on 'labels' that are attached to boxes but can change its placement by assignment, whereas in other languages, assignment changes the box's contents  (and the assignment operator can be overloaded).

Beginners can write quite complex applications without being aware of that, but they are usually messy programs.